# Update data to SQL Server with While java

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

So i'm trying to input data into my sql server with condition, i printout the value and nothing is wrong with the method, but the prepare statement only add one same data to the table, here is my code

```
public static void tunjanganKaryawan(){
    try {
        Staff  staff = new Staff();
        Statement stmt=getConn().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from list_karyawan where Status ='Tetap'");
        while(rs.next()){
            staff.setCuti(rs.getInt("Cuti") + rs.getInt("Tanpa_Kabar"));
            staff.setjmlhAbsensi(rs.getInt("Absensi"));
            int makan1 = (int) staff.gethitungTunjanganMakan();
            int Trans = (int) staff.gethitungTunjanganTrans();
            System.out.println(makan1+" "+Trans);

            String query = "update list_karyawan set Tunjangan_Makan = ? ,Tunjangan_Trans = ? where Status = 'Tetap'";
            ps =  getConn().prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1,makan1);
            ps.setInt(2,Trans);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

> Here is the result when i print out the makan and trans

```
200000 400000
170000 340000
170000 340000
130000 260000
170000 340000
```

and here is the data in the table
[image]

which the prepared statement only exceute the same value....

Comment: Your update says “every row which has Tetap in this column should have these values.” If you want them for a singe row you should use the unique ID as a condition

Comment: where i have to fix it..

Comment: what happens is that your while loop changes all values to 200000 400000 first, then the next values, then next values until final 170000 340000.  Your where condition is too general.

Comment: uhm is there any ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql query

```sql
update list_karyawan set Tunjangan_Makan = ? ,Tunjangan_Trans = ? where Status = 'Tetap'
```

will update all records where `Status = 'Tetap'` instead of a single record at a time. Moreover, `select *` is pulling more data from your database, i.e. using more resources than your desired use case. I would recommend selecting fields that are required instead eg

```sql
select ID,Cuti,Tanpa_Kabar,Absensi  from list_karyawan where Status ='Tetap'
```

In order to update separate records, using a unique identifier such as your `ID` column in the where condition in your sql statement will solve your issue. The recommended modifications have been included below:

```java
public static void tunjanganKaryawan(){
    try {
        Staff  staff = new Staff();
        Statement stmt=getConn().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select ID,Cuti,Tanpa_Kabar,Absensi  from list_karyawan where Status ='Tetap'");
        while(rs.next()){
            staff.setCuti(rs.getInt("Cuti") + rs.getInt("Tanpa_Kabar"));
            staff.setjmlhAbsensi(rs.getInt("Absensi"));
            int makan1 = (int) staff.gethitungTunjanganMakan();
            int Trans = (int) staff.gethitungTunjanganTrans();
            System.out.println(makan1+" "+Trans);

            String query = "update list_karyawan set Tunjangan_Makan = ? ,Tunjangan_Trans = ? where ID=?";
            ps =  getConn().prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1,makan1);
            ps.setInt(2,Trans);
            ps.setInt(3,rs.getInt("ID")); //use id from previous query
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```